# как передать "тяжелую" строку?

Tags: java, строки

В переменной - свёрстанная страница письма. При компиляции ошибка:

> Error:(138, 17) java: constant string too long

Как мне передать эту переменную в метод? Разрезать-забить массив-передать массивом? Потоком?

Comment: Загрузить строку из файла?

Comment: я подставляю в строку параметры из других переменных (имя, фамилия, должность), они не потеряются?

Comment: а зачем держать сверстанную страницу в переменной? Возьмите и держите уникальные параметры в листе, а верстку держите внутри метода, а дальше уже рисуйте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По [спецификации виртуальной машины](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7) Java максимальная длина строкового литерала — 65535. Определить в коде строковую константу большей длины не получится.

Обойти это можно несколькими способами.

1. Загружать строку из текстового файла/базы данных/конфигурации приложения и т.п.
2. Разбить строку на подстроки допустимой длины и определить ее так, чтобы компилятор не считал ее константой.

Например:

```
 String tmp = "";
 String value = tmp+
        "длинная подстрока 1 ... (еще 60000 символов)"+
        "длинная подстрока 2 ... (еще 60000 символов)"+
        ....
        "длинная подстрока n ... (еще 60000 символов)";
```

Рекоммендую первый способ, т.к. хранить такие строки в коде неудобно как для строк (сверстанную страницу нужно будет изменять), так и для кода (переписывать код посреди которого гигантский блок текста неудобно).

Полезные ссылки:

- [Вопрос по ошибке «constant string too long» на StackOverflow с альтернативными вариантами решения проблемы.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738574/java-constant-string-too-long-compile-error-only-happens-using-ant-not-when)
- [Вопрос на StackOverflow по максимальной длине строкового литерала.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323082/size-of-initialisation-string-in-java)
- [Java Tutorial. Основы чтения/записи.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)
- [Java Tutorial. Файлы конфигурации.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)